# Flot x-axsis is not plotting correctly ,only one data point is plotted

Tags: jquery, flot

```js
$(function () {
      var data = [[
       [1456819200000,199.8],
                [1456905600000,219.24],
                [1456992000000,589.68],
                [1457078400000,362.88],
                [1457337600000,145.56],
                [1457424000000,589.68],
                [1457510400000,60.48],
                [1457596800000,547.2],
                [1457938800000,239.4],
      
      var ticks = data[0].map(function (point) { return point[0]; });
     $.plot($("#placeholder"), [data],{ 
       xaxis: {
         mode: "time",
         ticks: ticks,
         minTickSize: [1,"day"],
         min: 1456819200000
         max: 1459321200000
         timeformat: "%d"
       },
       series: {
         lines: {
           show: true,
         },
         points: {
           show: true
         },
       },
       legend: {
         show: false
       },
       yaxis: {
         ticks: 5,
         tickDecimals: 0,
       }
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

I am following - http://jsfiddle.net/JMBucknall/eQ2eb/ fiddle

I am getting only one data point on chart

Comment: huh! least information,could you please elaborate some more, what output do you expect?

Comment: I should be able to see data across the chart as the data ranges from Mar 1 to Mar 30. I don't see x-axises show ticks as configured in the chart

Comment: what is `sdate` and `edate` here? these are undefined!

Comment: in comments do you see timestamp? it's already there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention me, I decided to help out and find the bugs. Let me count the ways:

1. Put the script tag for jQuery before that of flot.js
2. Add a script tag for [flot.time.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.time.js) after them both.
3. You declare a data source that's exactly of the right format (an array of data series, each of which is an array of chart points, each of which is an array containing an x and a y value) for `$.plot()`, yet you just throw in something called `[contract]`. It should be `$.plot("#placeholder", data, configuration);` I've no idea where `contract` came from.
4. As has been mentioned your code has some objects called `edate` and `sdate` from which you're calling some functions. They are not defined anywhere in this code. I replaced them with your commented values.
5. In order to actually see this chart (which you've declared as white on a default white background, I changed the `colors` property of the configuration object from white to black.

And that would be it apart from the fact that these days I'd write something like this to set the `ticks` array:

```
var ticks = data[0].map(function (point) { return point[0]; });
```

Comment: Thank you for corrections, point 3 is type error, edate and sdate is using javascript function. and updated my post. It see I have more issues....

Comment: Don't put `data` into an array: it defines an array already that will work just fine with `plot` (read point 3 again and compare to your changed code).

Also you are missing commas in your declaration of the `xaxis` property.

Look: whenever I write a new chart in flot, I always create the chart with no configuration (that's what I did with your example). If that works, I can add the configuration options I want and test it after every little change. It seems to me you're throwing the kitchen sink at this, and are not even sure any more what is right and what is wrong.